# How does one import python files from the same sub-directory?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a project with the Panda3D game engine. I have the files stored in `C:/%users%/Documents/Python/Starbound`. Here is the directory of the project:

```
Starbound
|--.git
|  |--all the git system stuff
|--__pycache__
|  |--__init__.cpython-37.pyc
|  |--main.cpython-37.pyc
|  |--run.cpython-37.pyc
|--__init_.py
|--main.py
|--run.py
```

I would like to use `run.py` as an easy command-line quick-run for the project. It is a script designed to call the main application as a library. This allows me to change the order of the setup without accidentally messing up the main program. When I call `run.py` from Windows CMD(in the Starbound directory), I get a traceback to line 9 of `run.py`:

`'loadWorld' missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

When I import `run.py` from the Python interpreter, I get a different traceback to line 5 of `run.py`:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'`

run.py:

```py
#run.py
#File to call "main.py"

#from Starbound import main
import main
print("Import of main file successful.")
App = main.Application
print("Declaration of application class successful.")
App.loadWorld()
print("Loading of world successful.")
```

main.py:

```py
#main.py
#File which contains the application control. Designed to be called from "run.py".

from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase
from direct.task import Task
from direct.actor.Actor import Actor
from direct.interval.IntervalGlobal import Sequence
from panda3d.core import Point3

class Application(ShowBase):
    #variables

    def __init__(self):
        ShowBase.__init__(self)

    def loadMainMenu(self):
        print("Main menu is not currently available.")

    def loadWorld(self):
        self.scene = self.loader.loadModel('models/environment')
        self.scene.reparentTo(self.render)
```

`__init__.py`

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/Starbound')
```

How do I call the `main.py` from `__init__.py` and other files?

Visual Studio 2019 installation of Python 3.7.5, Windows 10 Home.

Comment: seems like at the very least you're missing parenthesis when you create the `Application` instance on line 7 of `run.py`

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite Good grief that’s embarrassing! When I get back to my PC I will put those in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to call a python *package*, create a `__main__.py` file inside of it. It can be called with `python -m mymodule` (calls mymodule.**main**).